# How to use eval Makefile variable from recipe to conditionally execute some commands in recipe

Tags: bash, makefile, recipe

Goal is to apply patch ONLY if patch is not present. If patch is present don't do anything.
I used below makefile rule.

```
C_FILE_PATCH_SIG=###MAGIC_CODE;

C_FILE_CODE=~/code/file.c
C_PATCH_FILE=~/test.patch

.tmp/patch_c:
    cp ${C_PATCH_FILE} ${SDK}
ifneq ($(PATCH_DONE), 1)
    $(MAKE) applypatch || $(MAKE) helppatch
endif
    @echo DONE > .tmp/patch_c

applypatch:
    @echo "Patching ${C_FILE_CODE}"
    if grep -Fq '${C_FILE_PATCH_SIG}' ${C_FILE_CODE} ; \
    then \
    echo 1 > .tmp/PATCH_PRESENT_file; \
    else \
    echo 0 > .tmp/PATCH_PRESENT_file;\
    fi
    cat .tmp/PATCH_PRESENT_file
#   $(eval PATCH_PRESENT := `cat .tmp/PATCH_PRESENT_file`)
    $(eval PATCH_PRESENT := $(shell cat .tmp/PATCH_PRESENT_file))
    @echo "WWWWWW  PATCH_PRESENT=[$(PATCH_PRESENT)]  WWWWWWW"
ifeq ($(PATCH_PRESENT), 0)
    @echo "Applying the patch $(PATCH_PRESENT)"
    cd ~/code && git apply -v ${C_PATCH_FILE}
else
    @echo "NOT Applying the patch $(PATCH_PRESENT)"
endif

helppatch:
    @echo -e "\n\n\n"
    @echo -e "++++++++++ Apply below patch manually then run 'make build PATCH_DONE=1' ++++++++++\n\n"
    @echo -e "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
    @cat ${C_PATCH_FILE}
    @echo -e "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
    @echo -e "\n\n\n"
    false
```

But it always evaluates to the else part of ifeq.
Where am I doing wrong?

If I use the patch command of git withing the shell multiline I loose the error code returned by the git patch.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Which version of make do you use?

Comment: I think `C_FILE_PATCH_SIG` is always empty in your case, because `#` is a comment in make file, so assignmet `C_FILE_PATCH_SIG=###MAGIC_CODE;` is equivalent to `C_FILE_PATCH_SIG=`

Comment: You could redirect the error code to a file, if that would solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your `ifeq` will be evaluated when the makefile is first read (as opposed to when the recipe is run).  The `eval`, on the other hand, will not be executed until the recipe is run (afterwards).   Thus, `PATCH_PRESENT` is not equal to `0` at parse time, and make will expand the else portion of the clause.   By the time the `eval` is run, the if statement is already evaluated and gone from memory.

BTW, a cleaner way to do this is to do everything in bash:

```
applypatch:
    @echo "Patching ${C_FILE_CODE}"
    @if grep -Fq '${C_FILE_PATCH_SIG}' ${C_FILE_CODE}; then \
         echo "NOT Applying the patch"; \
     else \
         echo "Applying the patch"; \
         cd ~/code && git apply -v ${C_PATCH_FILE}; \
     fi
```

Comment: If bash complains via makefile stderr about execting 'fi' not end of the file it's because bash command is pretty much oneliner and consecutive echo, cd and whatnots need to be separated by semicolons ;

Comment: Thanks -- fixed.

Comment: Wow, thx for the fix. Didn't want to touch your answer :-)